# CSOM : create a folder and add items

Tags: 2013, csom

I have code to create a folder and add items to the folder . I have used CSOM to do this particulat operation . Since this is async code , sometimes the folder is not created and add items is getting fired with error . How to handle something like this? Is there any code example to create folder in list and add items and overcome above scenario.

```
function CreateNewfolder(loginuserid, strTitle) {

    var Context;
    var oWebsite;
    var oList;
    var itemCreateInfo;
    var myListItemCreationInfo;
    Context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = Context.get_web();
    List = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("List");
    var itemurl = "/Lists/" + List + "/" + loginUSERID;
    checkfolderexist();

        if (checkfolderexist() == false) {
            itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
            itemCreateInfo.set_leafName(loginUSERID);
            this.oListItem = List.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            this.oListItem.set_item('Title', loginUSERID);
            this.oListItem.set_item('Name', strTitle);

            this.oListItem.update();
            oWebsite.update();
            Context.load(this.oListItem);
            Context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandlerFolder), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandlerFolder));

            function successHandlerFolder( {
                console.log(" Create Folder Method success");
                CreateNewFiles(loginUSERID, strTitle);
            }
            function errorHandlerFolder() {
                console.log(" Create Folder Method fail " + JSON.stringify(error));

            }
        }
        else {
            CreateNewFiles(loginUSERID,strTitle);
        }


}

function CreateNewFiles(loginUSERID, strTitle) {
    var listName = "MyFavorites";
    var clientContext;
    var oWebsite;
    var oList;
    var itemCreateInfo;
    var myListItemCreationInfo;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var Website = clientContext.get_web();
    oList = Website.get_lists().getByTitle("List");
    var myListItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var folderUrl = "/Lists/List/" + loginUSERID;
    myListItemCreationInfo.set_folderUrl(folderUrl);
    this.newLinkItem = oList.addItem(myListItemCreationInfo);
    this.newLinkItem.set_item('Title', url);
    this.newLinkItem.set_item('Name', strTitle);
    this.newLinkItem.update();
    oList.update();
    Website.update();
    clientContext.load(this.newLinkItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));

    function successHandler() {

    }

    function errorHandler() {

    }
}

function checkfolderexist() {

    var listTitle = 'List';
    var fileUrl = "/Lists/List/" + loginUSERID;


    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
    qry.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileRef"/><Value Type="Url">' + fileUrl + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    var items = list.getItems(qry);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        fileFound = (items.get_count() > 0);
        return fileFound;

    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });

}
```

Comment: the error handler of  checkfolderexist() should return false also. May I give you REST API solution using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

`checkfolderexist` also makes an async call and can't return the result immediately. However, your code is treating as if `checkfolderexist` can return result synchronously.

You can logically structure your code like this:

- `checkfolderexist`

  - `executeQueryAsync success`

    - `items.get_count() > 0`: Folder is found, just call C`reateNewFiles`
    - `else`: Create folder (your existing code)

      - `executeQueryAsync` of create folder success: call `CreateNewFiles`
      - `executeQueryAsync` of create folder fail: Show error
  - `executeQueryAsyn`c of `checkfolderexist` fail: Show error

You should probably rename your functions if you follow this structure.

Comment: If you also add Promises your script will be better to read and more modular as well. Scott Hillier did a decent blog some years ago: http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/03/04/using-promises-with-the-javascript-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx